# How to load content into dynamically created TabItems On-Demand/Lazy Load?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, lazy-loading, tabcontrol, ondemand

I have a tab control defined in my app and I'm adding tab items to it dynamically. Lets say I have list of objects with lots of data and for each object I show 5-10 tabs. The ordering and the tabs shown differ from object to object. That is why I have to dynamically create these tabs based on my object.

As far as the content inside these tab items go, I generally set the .Content property of each tab to a UserControl and it loads it as shown in below code.

```
If ContainsFingerprints() Then
        Dim fingerprintT As New TabItem
        fingerprintT.Content = New FingerprintTab()
        fingerprintT.Header = "Fingerprints"
        fingerprintT.Name = "tiFingerprintTab"
        viewTab.Items.Add(fingerprintT)
End If
```

Some of these tabs have lots of images and take up lot of memory at run time. That is why I would like to load Content in those tab items 'on-demand', that is, only when the tab is selected.

I could use the SelectionChanged event of the tab control and then load the required content but is there a better solution that WPF offers?

Comment: Can you let instead content to nothing and only set the content to what is needed when Selected event is triggered based on the condition if Content is nothing then New Fingerprinttab() ? Wouldn't that do exactly what you mean ?

Comment: I can use the SelectionChanged event of the Tab Control but In this approach I need to loop through all the tab items and then again find out which tab to load based on selection. Iwas wondering if there  is better solution that WPF offers involving maybe bindings and handlers or using the Lazy(Of T), have never used Lazy so I don't know if its possible using it. Thanks, I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I tried using the Load and Unload event handlers but the tab's load event triggers as soon as it is created so it did not help. Also tried working with some kind of style binding with IsSelected property but could not get it work.